# LinkedList add method

Tags: c#

So,Im creating an add method for a linked list wich im making from scratch. I want the list to add Items (Nodes with int value) anywhere in the list. Here is my code:

```
public void Add(int val)
{
   Node newNode = new Node();
   newNode.value = val;

   if (head == null)
   {
       head = newNode;
       current = newNode;
   }

   if (current.Next == null)
   {
       current.Next = newNode;
       current = newNode;

   }
   size++;
}
```

Now, when i tried my program I noticed that I only can add values linear in the list. Am I completely on the wrong side of the train?

For example:
*I have 3 elements in my list, 1, 7, 9 and I want to add the item 2 to my list after element 1?*

Comment: Is `current` supposed to point to the last element? Consider renaming it to `last` or `tail`.

Comment: Current is declared outside the method in the linkedlist class. It keeps track on the current node in the list (last node), as it always moves forward when new nodes are inserted.

Comment: Under what circumstances would `current.Next` not be null then? Your question and your code lack a lot of detail.

Comment: It's unclear from your question what you are asking.

Comment: To implement [linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) you need `InsertAfter`/`InsertBefore`. What `Add` suppose to do? Add after last or insert before first?

Comment: Why not use LinkedList<int> ?

Comment: thats the thing. Since my current (tail) every time points to the end of the list, current.next will always be null then. So I cant reach the nodes thats in the middle of the list.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
public void Add(int val)
{
   Node newNode = new Node();
   newNode.value = val;

   if (head == null)
   {
       head = newNode;
       current = newNode;
   }
   else
   {
       current.Next = newNode;
       current = newNode;
   }
   size++;
}

public void Insert(int index, int val)
{
   // COMPLETELY UNTESTED BUT MAY POINT YOU IN THE RIGHT DIRECTION
   Node newNode = new Node();
   newNode.value = val;


   if (head == null) { return; }

   Node node = new Node();
   if (index == 0){
      newNode.Next = head;
      head = newNode;
   } 
   node = head;

   while(node.Head!=null && index > 1)
   {
      node = node.Next;
      index--;
   }
   if (node != null && index >= 0){
      var next = node.Next;
      newNode.Next = next;
      node.Next = newNode;
   }
   size++;
}
```

Comment: Oh okey.But what if I have 3 elements in my list, 1, 7, 9 and I want to add the item 2 to my list after element 1? Thanks!

Comment: That is `Insert` and the usual arguments is the wanted index and the item so `Insert(int index, int val)`, then you should step away from `head` using `.Next` `index` times and insert.

Comment: To insert `newNode` after a `node` use this logic: `var prevNext = node.Next; newNode.Next = prevNext; node.Next = newNode`;

Comment: added some off the top of my head code for Insert, may point you in the right direction - I can't guarantee it will work

Comment: As I understand now, the add method just adds element to the end of the list, but the insert method inserts nodes from any given index value. So depending on where I want to add, I should use the right method, right?

Comment: And why is it that you created 2 different nodes in the insert method? (newNode and node)

Comment: newNode holds the data for the new Node, node is the node I use to traverse the linked list from it's head

Answer (score 0):

What you'll want to do is start at the head of the list, then traverse it till you get to the appropriate spot, then insert it. Something like this:

```
public void Add(int val)
{
    var newNode = new Node();
    Node currentNode = head;
    int index=0;

    while (currentNode != null && index < val)
    {
        currentNode=currentNode.Next;
        index++;
    }

    newNode.Next = currentNode.Next;
    currentNode.Next = newNode;
    // If its a doubly linked list, you might need to update .Prev too
}
```

What this is doing is traversing each node, incrementing an index counter as we do so. When we finally get to the right spot, we are taking the node that the current node points to and having our new node point to it instead. Then we point the current node's Next property to our new node, thus "inserting" our new node after the current node.